# Laravel Bootstrap-Modal TokenMismatch

Tags: jquery, laravel, modal-dialog, token, bootstrap-modal

I´ve got a Problem with in Laravel with Bootstrap-Modal.

The simple Modal works great, but when I use "Varying modal content based",
I get an Error:

This Script on my Mainside:

```
$('#renameModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
      var recipient = button.data('entity_input') 
      var entity = button.data('entity')
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
    })
```

produces this Error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67

I have the Line: `{!! csrf_field() !!}` in my code, but when I
use the `JQuery`-Script, it doesn't work.

Anyone knows how to solve the Problem??

The Modal Code:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="renameModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Umbenennen</h4>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="{{ url('user_rename/'.$user[0]->id) }}" method="POST">
                       {!! csrf_field() !!}
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Abbrechen>
                    <button type="submit" id="rename-user{{ $user[0]->id }}" class="btn btn-primary">Speichern</button>
                  </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

Sry for bad format ;-(

Comment: show us the modal code

Comment: Does it change if you modify your url to /user_rename instead of user_rename?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are changing the value of the hidden csrf token.

```
modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
```

**{!! csrf_field() !!}** produces something like this and is above your **input#recipient-name**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="some-random-token">
```

In your Javascript change `modal.find('.modal-body input')` to `modal.find('.modal-body input#recipient-name')`. It's also worth noting you haven't given your recipient-name input an actual field name.